# jQuery .each() to get values of multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to calculate the width and difference between the widths of a div and the text in a page where the same div class appears multiple times.

The HTML:

```
<div class="post_content">
       <div class="container">
          <div class="title-holder">
          <h2><a href="link.html" class="widget-title">Crossword Book</a></h2>
          </div>
       </div>

      <div class="container">
         <div class="title-holder">
         <h2><a href="link.html" class="widget-title">Crossword Bookstore Ltd. &ndash; Elgin Road</a></h2>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
div.container{
  width: 130px;
}
div.title-holder {
  width: 130px;
  height:20px;
  text-align:center;
  background: silver;
  overflow:hidden;
  position: relative;
}
div.title-holder a {  
  position: relative;  
  white-space:nowrap;  
  left: 0px;
}
div.image{
  background: brown;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

The following script outputs the result of the first div correctly and then repeats the same result. It is not going to the next div and giving the next result.

```
$("div.title-holder").each(function(){    
  var m = $(this).width();
  var n = $("div.title-holder h2 a.widget-title").width();
  var o = m - n;

  alert ("title: " + m + " text: " + n + " diff: " + o);    

});
```

The output is

```
First Alert: title: 130 text: 108 diff: 22
Second Alert: title: 130 text: 108 diff: 22
```

What I am looking to achieve is

```
First Alert: title: 130 text: 108 diff: 22
Second Alert: title: 130 text: 258 diff: -128
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of:

```
var n = $("div.title-holder h2 a.widget-title").width();
```

Will always be the same (the first result of that selector query). You need to do:

```
var n = $(this).find("a.widget-title").width();
```

or more specific:

```
var n = $("div.title-holder").children("h2").children("a.widget-title").width();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was missing out the obvious. :)

Comment: In the latter case you can say "div.title-holder > h2 > a.widget-title" which is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Use like this:

```
var n = $(this).find("h2 a.widget-title").width();
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsBin demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/VGNF2/)

```
$("div.title-holder").each(function(){    
  var m = $(this).width();
  var n = $("h2 a.widget-title", this).width();
  var o = m - n;

  alert("title: " + m + " text: " + n + " diff: " + o);    

});
```